# Is there a java api which I can use for a permutation of numbers to find out canonical form of its equivalence classes?

Tags: java, permutation, combinatorics, equivalence-classes

Is there a java api which I can use for a permutation of numbers to find out canonical form of its equivalence classes ?
It is required for all possible guesses for [Mastermind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29).
As per the [document](http://slovesnov.users.sourceforge.net/bullscows/bulls_and_cows.pdf) .

**EDIT** :Let me explain by example what I am looking for 
Example : In order to solve the game of in minimum steps we have to give our guesses and based on the response decide the next guess . 
Lets say for 4 pegs and 6 colors ( total combination = 1296  , repeat allowed ) .
For the initial try we only need to consider one possible guess lets say **0011** and the response we get is 1 Black and 0 White.**(1,0)**.
Now, We check 0011 against all the 1296 numbers and keep all those which return (1,0). Thus, our solution is somewhere inside this *reduced sample set*. 
Now for the second query using ***equivalence transformations*** as mentioned in the document possible codes are reduced for second try.

Now, I want to know if there an any existing java api which I can use for a given set of permutations ( reduced set after (0,1) on 1296 ) and get ***equivalence transformations*** on my inputs ?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes, but it's true that the question lacks some details. First of all, the document describes a game that differs slightly from MasterMind, and fleshing out how these differences may affect the solution may be difficult. In any case, it would be helpful if you showed (in the question!) what "equivalence" refers to. I assume that you want to obtain the list of possible combinations that would result in the response that one received for a particular guess. Is this correct? (If so, describe this precisely in the question!)

Comment: What equivalence classes do you mean? Do you mean cosets for some permutation group --- a subgroup of symmetric group?

Comment: Our do you mean   equivalence classes induced by some automorphism of permutation group (e.g. g~h if g,h belongs to same orbit under automorphism)?

Comment: Added an example to explain what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Consider using sorting to find the equivalence classes.

By sorting `1010` and `1001` you each time get `0011`.